# Howe to get ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE field value in python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Using cx_Oracle 5.2.1 with Oracle client library 11.2 and Oracle server 11.2, I am unable to retrieve the content of an `ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE` field.
The following code raises `attribute read not found exception`:

```
import cx_Oracle
db = cx_Oracle.Connection('user/pass@ip/t')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select IMAGE from T where ROWID in ('AAAAAAAAAA')")
bf, = cursor.fetchone()
bfile_data = bf.read()
```

The exception raised is: `AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.OBJECT' object has no attribute 'read'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that cx_Oracle.OBJECT does not have a read() method. Instead, it has attributes which you can read/write just like any other Python object.

Using the unreleased version of cx_Oracle the following generic code will work:

```
def ObjectRepr(obj):
    if obj.type.iscollection:
        returnValue = []
        for value in obj.aslist():
            if isinstance(value, cx_Oracle.Object):
                value = ObjectRepr(value)
            returnValue.append(value)
    else:
        returnValue = {}
        for attr in obj.type.attributes:
            value = getattr(obj, attr.name)
            if value is None:
                continue
            elif isinstance(value, cx_Oracle.Object):
                value = ObjectRepr(value)
            returnValue[attr.name] = value
    return returnValue

print(ObjectRepr(bf))
```

If you are using 5.2.1, though, some of the introspective code is not available. Fortunately, you don't need that. You can describe the type in SQL*Plus which will show you the list of attributes at the beginning of its output

```
desc ordsys.ordimage
```

That should allow you to do the following in your Python code:

```
print(bf.HEIGHT)
print(bf.WIDTH)
print(bf.CONTENTLENGTH)
print(bf.FILEFORMAT)
```

Note that the attribute SOURCE is yet another object so you can access its attributes in the same way:

```
print(bf.SOURCE.SRCNAME)
print(bf.SOURCE.UPDATETIME)
```

and so forth.

The attribute bf.SOURCE.LOCALDATA is of type BLOB which is currently unsupported. You can access its value using an anonymous PL/SQL block instead:

```
var = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.BLOB)
cursor.execute("""
        declare
            t_Image ordsys.ordimage;
        begin
            select Image
            into t_Image
            from T
            where rownum <= 1;

            :1 := t_Image.source.localdata;

        end;""", (var,))
blob = var.getvalue()
print("Image data is:", blob.read())
```

Comment: Would you please let me know how to get the content of the image self, not the attributes?

Comment: I haven't used ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE but I would guess you need to access bf.SOURCE.LOCALDATA. You can confirm by using PL/SQL code to access it instead first.

Comment: I don't know how to check with PL/SQL first, but using bf.SOURCE.LOCALDATA raises `NotSupportedError: ExternalObjectVar_GetAttributeValue(): unhandled data type 113` exception.

Comment: Ah, that is a BLOB which is currently unsupported, unfortunately. You should be able to access it via an anonymous PL/SQL block until such time as that support is added.

Comment: I updated my answer to include how to get the BLOB data out until such time as it is supported properly in cx_Oracle.